# Problems with wifi HP 15-ay031ns and Ubuntu (both 16.04.1 LTS and 14.04 LTS)

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, broadcom, hp

I bought a laptop (HP 15-ay031ns) with Windows 10 preinstalled. But I need to install also Ubuntu in dual boot. The problem is that I'm not able to connect to any wifi network, it seems that is a problem with the drivers.

With Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS I spent two days trying different options, also using the responses from other questions here in "askubuntu", I managed to connect to the wifi network after reinstalling the bcmwl-kernel-source driver and removing the Secure Boot, but the network speed is very low (0.5 Mbps) while in my old laptop the speed is 10 Mbps.

With Ubuntu 14.04 LTS it is easier, because it seems to connect directly to the wifi network without any reinstallations, but the speed is the same: 0.5 Mbps.

If I connect an external wifi device to connect the network, the speed raises to 5 Mpbs.

In Windows 10 the network speed is correct.

This is the information that I'm able to get in the terminal:

```
Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)

03:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n (rev 01)
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 804a
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
Memory at a2100000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: wl
```

I have tried to install the following packages but for some of them the wifi does not work and for other the speed is very low:

```
bcmwl-kernel-source

broadcom-sta-common

broadcom-sta-dkms

b43-fwcutter
```

I also tried these solutions:

[Unable to connect wifi ubuntu 14.04 LTS HP Pavilion Network driver rtl8723be](https://askubuntu.com/questions/645220/unable-to-connect-wifi-ubuntu-14-04-lts-hp-pavilion-network-driver-rtl8723be)

[Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)