# Wifi configuration: what do those variable mean?

Tags: wireless, rtl8723be

I am configuring my wifi, and it's working pretty well. I just want to know if I can make it work better. I've searched and I haven't found an answer to the meaning of ALL these variables:[ant_sel, debug, fwlps, ips, swenc, (bool), disable_watchdog, (int), msi, swlps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dgwSV.png), specially fwlps, ips, swenc and disable_watchdog.

I am searching for how to open the manual of this or just the meanings.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command `modinfo rtl8723be` gives a brief explanation:

```
parm:  swenc:Set to 1 for software crypto (default 0) (bool)
parm:  ips:Set to 0 to not use link power save (default 1) (bool)
parm:  swlps:Set to 1 to use SW control power save (default 0) (bool)
parm:  fwlps:Set to 1 to use FW control power save (default 1) (bool)
parm:  msi:Set to 1 to use MSI interrupts mode (default 0) (bool)
parm:  aspm:Set to 1 to enable ASPM (default 1) (int)
parm:  debug_level:Set debug level (0-5) (default 0) (int)
parm:  debug_mask:Set debug mask (default 0) (ullong)
parm:  disable_watchdog:Set to 1 to disable the watchdog (default 0) (bool)
parm:  ant_sel:Set to 1 or 2 to force antenna number (default 0) (int)
```

I suspect that the parameter you are most interested in is `ant_sel` as antenna selection is a known issue for your device: [Unable to connect wifi ubuntu 14.04 LTS HP Pavilion Network driver rtl8723be](https://askubuntu.com/questions/645220/unable-to-connect-wifi-ubuntu-14-04-lts-hp-pavilion-network-driver-rtl8723be/729660#729660)